# Generalized Inverse of GA & J

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-inverse

Let $J$ be a $n \times n$ matrix of 1's and $A$ is a $n \times m$ matrix with generalized inverse $G$. i.e. $AGA = A$.

I'm trying to find a generalized inverse of $GA$ and $J$.

Am I correct to say a generalized inverse of $GA$ is just itself, $GA$, since:

$GAGAGA = GAGA = GA$

and the generalized inverse of J is $\frac{1}{n}I_{n}$ since:

$J\frac{1}{n}I_{n}J =\frac{1}{n}J^{2} = \frac{n}{n}J = J$

Comment: Don't you need to check more than that one condition? The definition I'm familiar of the generalized inverse $A^{\dagger}$ of $A$ requires (i) $A^{\dagger}AA^{\dagger} = A^{\dagger}$, (ii) $AA^{\dagger}A = A$ (the condition you check), (iii) $AA^{\dagger}$ Hermitian; (iv) $A^{\dagger}A$ Hermitian...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well I just guessed these matrices based on the definition, how would I formally find a g-inverse here?

Comment: I think you're doing fine; but my point is that at least with the definition I'm familiar with, I would need to check *more* than what you've checked so far.